# Highlight hover area in image with mapper.js only works when the page reload

Tags: javascript, html

I got a hold of this mapper.js from http://www.netzgesta.de/mapper to highlight an area in my image.  I was only able to get it to sorta work...well...it only works after I fresh the page.

My html:

```
<% provide(:title, "World Map") %>
<script type="text/javascript" src="wz_jsgraphics.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="mapper.js"></script>
<h3>World Map</h3>
<div class="map">
  <%= image_tag("map.png", :usemap => "#worldmap", :class => "mapper") %>
    <map name="worldmap">
      <area shape="rect" coords="505,244,546,278" class="noborder">
      <area shape="rect" coords="481,189,503,207" class="noborder">
    </map>
</div>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem...it has to do with Turbolinks in Rails.  Turned it off and it works.